# RDLC/Reporting Services: Gauge inside table is cut off

Tags: reporting-services, rdlc, report-designer

I'm designing a `RDLC` report using `Microsoft Report Designer`, where I have a Gauge inside a cell in a Tablix.

The problem I'm having is that the, no matter what I do, the Gauge gets cut off at the bottom.

Here's what I have in the designer:
[image]

And here is how it gets rendered in the final document:
[image]

As you can see: the bottom and right portion are cut off, and the scale labels and bar of the gauge are bigger than expected. It's like the Gauge is "zoomed in" (i.e.: rendered bigger than it should be) and then cut off.

Does anyone know why is this happening?

**EDIT:**
Editing the question because I found the root of the problem, but I still don't know how to fix it (if it can be fixed). Here it goes:

A necessary clarification that I didn't report in the original question (I didn't think the problem would be related to something like this): I'm rendering the report to a `ReportViewer` control inside a `WPF` app.

After noticing that if I rendered the report directly to a PDF document the problem disappeared, I understood that it wasn't a problem with the report itself, but rather with the `ReportViewer`. Some more digging and I discovered there is a known issue with `ReportViewer` when the display DPI scaling is set to more than 100% in the Windows settings (which was my case: I was working on a 4k display set to 150% scaling)

There are some solutions here on StackOverflow and elsewhere that involve changing the app's DPI awareness, but they all seem to be targeted at Windows Forms applications. I didn't find anything that worked in my case, that is: a WPF application that is hosting `ReportViewer` inside it through the `WindowsFormsHost` control.

I'll leave the question open in case someone has a working solution for this particular case.

Comment: I tried to reproduce this as a standard RDL and its working fine. Have you check that the `CanGrow` property of all the textboxess is set to `True`?

Comment: @AlanSchofield: thanks for your help. You're right, in the sense that the report itself is not the problem, it's something else. Please see my update to the question for details.

Comment: Understood. I can't help you but you might want to review the question tags so they focus on where you think the issue is.